# ActiveMQ with slow consumer skips 200 messages

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, mule

I'm using ActiveMQ along with Mule (a kind of ESB based on Spring).
We got a fast producer and a slow consumer.
It's synchronous configuration with only one consumer.

Here the configuration of the consumer in spring style: http://pastebin.com/vweVd1pi

The biggest requirement is to keep the order of the messages.
However, after hours of running this code, suddenly, ActiveMQ skips 200 messages, and send the next ones.The 200 messages are still there in the activeMQ, they are not lost.
But our client (Mule), does have some custom code to check the order of the messages, using an unique identifier.

I had this issue already a few month ago. We change the consumer by using the parameter "jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1". It seemed to have worked well and to be the fix we needed unti now when the issue reappeared on another consumer.

Is it a bug, or a configuration issue ?

Comment: When you say the messages are skipped, and remain in ActiveMQ what does that mean? Are they in the queue(s) that you sent them to, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I can't talk about the requirement from a Mule perspective, but there are a couple of broker features that you should take a look at. There are two ways to guarantee message ordering in ActiveMQ:

[Message groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) are a way of ensuring that a set of related messages will be consumed by the same consumer in the order that they are placed on a *queue*. To use it you need to specify a JMSXGroupID header on related messages, and assign them an incrementing JMSXGroupSeq number. If a consumer dies, *remaining* messages from that group will be sent to another single consumer, while still preserving order.

[Total message ordering](http://activemq.apache.org/total-ordering.html) applies to all messages on a *topic*. It is configured on the broker on a per-destination basis and requires no particular changes to client code. It comes with a synchronisation overhead.

Both features allow you to scale out to more than one consumer.

Comment: do we have to have multiple consumers ? what about just not sending messages to the consumer if it's not ready to receive ? or having the consumer polling for more message when it's ready? Is there such strategy ? Or you think we must have a second Consumer that would take over if first one busy. We wanted to stay in a single consumer configuration.

Comment: You don't have to have multiple consumers, but the mechanisms for message ordering are the same and allow you to scale out for better performance. When you are using broker-based messaging, the broker is responsible for the hand-off of messages to the consumer. Prefetching optimizes that process to reduce network traffic - the messages go into a buffer on the client. The most common way to consume messages from there is asynchronously, by registering a message listener against a session (perhaps via a Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer).

Comment: ok, we have set the exclusive consumer setting and checked in the active mq admin query that it's actually considering the parameter. But we still have the same issues. It's always 200 messages that are skipped and processed later